# Do you pay for Subversion support?

Tags: svn, tfs, open-source

My team is looking to switch from source safe to something else (finally). I think we have it narrowed down to Team Server 2010 or Subversion.

I would prefer Subversion, but my boss has concerns about how we will get support if were using Subversion and something goes wrong. It was suggested that we [pay for support](http://www.open.collab.net/support/support-programs/).

So my question to those out there that use Subversion: Do you pay for support? Have you ever needed it?

Comment: How much did you pay for support when you were using source safe?

Comment: Probably should be CW since there is no correct answer. Unless you count me answering "no" as a correct answer?

Comment: @Rene - Its hard to say. It's part of MSDN license, but what ever it was it was too much.

Comment: So, I guess, if paying MSDN was too much for using an MS Product, it will probably too much if you pay for using SVN as well.

Comment: Hopefully you're considering Subversion vs. TFS in attributes other than support. TFS is a far broader product than Subversion is. Subversion is source-control only, where TFS addresses the problems of ALM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have never paid for support. We were always able to solve the issues ourselves or with the help of the community.

Answer (score 2):

No, we don't pay for it, haven't needed it.  Answers can be found on google or here on SO.  If I had an issue, I'd ask here on SO and would probably get an answer comparable to 2nd or 3rd level paid support, probably quicker.

Answer (score 1):

We use SVN, and do not have any kind of commercial support contract. Any time we have a question, we read the book or go the Subversion mailing lists (subversion.apache.org).

CollabNet provides SVN consulting and training, so if you are looking for someone to pay, they would be a good place to start. (www.collab.net)

Answer (score 1):

SVN has great documentation, and community support. Much easier to deal with than MS. If your worried about hosting, there are plenty of SVN hosting providers who will take care of the hosting aspect, check out svnhostingcomparison.com

Answer (score 0):

Subversion is open source. You will not pay for it. If something goes wrong there is a lot of great documentation and big community.

Answer (score 0):

99% of the time I'm able to figure out the problem my self.

There is also commercial sites that will host subversion for you.

-daniel

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to switch to Subversion and want support, I recommend you go with a hosted Subversion provider.  I work for [ProjectLocker](http://www.projectlocker.com) but if you Google "subversion hosting" a number of options come up.

The Subversion code base is incredibly stable and we've never had an issue with base functionality failing to work as advertised.  We've got some proprietary patches to portions of the product that we've written, but those are to solve our unique scaling needs, not because of shortcomings of the product.  In our experience, any single large installation will be more than adequately served by the standard code, even if you have hundreds of developers on your team.

Your support needs are more likely to be around either usage of the product or administration of the product.  For both, [The Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com) is a great guide that explains in detail how to use the product.  Most Subversion hosting providers also have technical support that can answer usage questions, and Web-based interfaces that make it easier to administrate the product.  Finally, putting a specific Subversion error message into Google goes a long way, people have been using this product in the wild for nearly 10 years and have seen everything there is to see.